# How alter overall coloring of a complex object?

Tags: color, art

I've got following fish object that needs new color:

[image]

If I change color the fish looks weird and all the outlines are gone (until I change stroke coloring).

Comment: Would you care to mention which software you are using?  You may need to ungroup the object, and apply strokes and fills to the individual parts.

Answer (score 3):

In general... Reduce, refine, simplify.

You **often** need to either redraw the object, or do some work to simplify the image overall. This is *especially* true if you are seeking to use a 1 color version of the image. You need to add hard contrast overall to ensure the details are seen in a single color.

I would choose to redraw the overall image using the original as a guide really, but not utilizing it directly.

When redrawing, I'd remove unnecessary detail, and add high-contrast detail where appropriate.

[image]

This reduced the image to a solid single color image which is clear at smaller sizes:

[image]

From there, it's a fairly easy matter to just apply a new color....

[image]

If usage requires even smaller sizes than this, additional attention to increasing the negative spaces may be required. The "gaps" tend to start plugging up around 100px wide.

Answer (score 2):

That image looks lile is taken from a vector program.

- Ungroup the objects and asign individual colors to individual objects.
- Re arrange the order of them if they are mixed.
- Rapir any open path.
- Clean the object, for example cut objects onw with another in case "hidding" it behind does not work.